# Dask read_csv fails where pandas doesn't

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Trying to use dask's `read_csv` on file where pandas's `read_csv` like this

```
dd.read_csv('data/ecommerce-new.csv')
```

fails with the following error:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 2
```

The file is csv file of scraped data using scrapy with two columns, one with the url and the other with the html(which is stored multiline using `"` as delimiter char). Being actually parsed by pandas means it should be actually well-formatted.

```
html,url
https://google.com,"<a href=""link"">
</a>"
```

Making the `sample` argument big enough to load the entire file in memory seems to work, which makes me believe it actually fails when trying to infer the datatypes(also there's this issue which 
should have been solved https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1284)

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is there a fix/workaround?

**EDIT:** Apparently this is a known problem with dask's read_csv if the file contains a newline character between quotes. A solution I found was to simply read it all in memory:

```
dd.from_pandas(pd.read_csv(input_file), chunksize=25)
```

This works, but at the cost of parallelism. Any other solution?

Comment: could you try something like `df = dd.read_csv(csvfile, delimiter="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, encoding='utf-8')` <- the quoting part is important here; you can also try `quoting=3` and `error_bad_lines=False`, but let's first try to see what the first gives you. :)

Comment: Tried it, not sure why exactly the delimiter was '\t' as i'm using commas for separation, but nonetheless, it yields this error now: `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 30, saw 2`

Comment: And when using comma as a delimiter: `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 21, saw 13`

Comment: You will need `blocksize=None` in `dd.read_csv`, which will read the whole file into one chunk - but you still get parallelism between files. Dask determines chunks by looking for `'\n'`, and you cannot know if one is an actual line separator without serially parsing through the file up to that point.

Answer (score 2):

For people coming here in 2020, the `dd.read_csv` works directly for newlines inside quotes. It has been fixed. Update to the latest version of Dask (`2.18.1` and above) to get these benefits.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('path_to_your_file.csv')
print(df.compute())
```

Gives,

```
                 html                    url
0  https://google.com  <a href="link">\n</a>
```

OR

For people who want to use an older version for some reason, as suggested by @mdurant you might wanna pass `blocksize=None` to `dd.read_csv` which will be at a cost of parallel loading.

Comment: Hi, could you please specify the version in which it hase been fixed, it would be very helpful.

Comment: @ArsenyNerinovsky I don't know the exact version where the fix was made, But I have `2.18.1` and it works in this version.

Comment: still having issues in 2020 with a freshly installed copy of dask :(

Comment: Checked it with a fresh install of `dask==2.30.0` and it works. I think you might have some other problem. @Sam