# Read GCS file into dask dataframe

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to read a csv file stored in Google Cloud Storage using dask dataframe.

I have insalled gcsfs & dask in the conda env. on Windows

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import gcsfs

project_id = 'my-project'
token_file = 'C:\\path\to\credentials.json'
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=project_id)
gcs_bucket_name = 'my_bucket'

df = dd.read_csv('gs://'+gcs_bucket_name+'/my_file.csv',storage_options={'token': token_file, 'project': project_id})
```

I know I'm not providing the key file correctly as per 
`https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/` but not sure how to do it. Can anyone please help?

Error I'm getting -

```
  File "<ipython-input-XXXXXXXX>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/path/to/scripts/my_python_script.py', wdir='C:/path/to/scripts')

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/path/to/scripts/my_python_script.py", line 28, in <module>
    df = dd.read_csv('gcs://'+gcs_bucket_name+'/my_file.csv',storage_options={'token': token_file, 'project': project_id})

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\csv.py", line 578, in read
    **kwargs

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\csv.py", line 444, in read_pandas
    head = reader(BytesIO(b_sample), **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 463, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1154, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2059, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 881, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 896, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 950, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 937, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2132, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 134
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? I tried your code and could read the csv from storage. Check variables and path to credentials.

Comment: The error suggests that this is dask-related. Try solutions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752805/dask-read-csv-fails-where-pandas-doesnt)

Comment: To clarify, your authentication is successfull, you can access the file. "Error tokenizing.." means that dask couldn't parse csv, either the csv file has defects or dask can't handle it due to its issues.

Comment: Thanks Emil! Understood the error and I think it's because even though my file is csv, somehow while uploading into GCS bucket it shows `Content-Type=application/vnd.ms-excel` how to change it to `text/csv`

Comment: Uploaded the file from cloud shell solved the problem

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit) you can find how to edit object metadata.